# Where are the red guys coming from in Darwinia?

Tags: darwinia

I'm on the level where you have to take over some laser satellite transponders and change them from red to green with darwinians.  I thought I had the whole level beat, and then suddenly I see red darwinians all over the place!  Where are they coming from?  How do I prevent this... do I just have to repeatedly slaughter them faster than they pop up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You know those big gates that you start out being able to spawn your programs close to?

Turns out that those nasty red darwinians are coming through there as well.

As far as I know, they keep coming indiscriminately -- the only recourse is to crash some armours into turrets, and set up a zone of deadly crossfire to blaze them when they warp in. You know where they're coming from, so bunker down and defend it!

Two turrets should be enough, just be careful not to place them too close to the portal, or the red darwinians might man them instead!

Answer (score 1):

Look at the label above the port they are coming through - that's your next level! And they won't stop sending reinforcements, so you have to setup 3 to 4 turrets per port.